# How to measure load time of a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm optimizing the scrolling smoothness of a UITableView, but it's tough to notice subtle gains by eye. I'm looking for a straightforward way to print out the "load time" of each UITableViewCell as it appears. Is this possible?

Comment: Interestingly, the jumpy scrolling turned out to be an issue with using `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and `tableView.estimatedRowHeight`. Going back to manual row height calculation using `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` appears to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things:

1: Measure execution time for `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

2: Measure execution time for `- reloadData`

#### Measuring:

```
- (UITableViewCell * _Nonnull)tableView:(UITableView * _Nonnull)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath * _Nonnull)indexPath {
   CFTimeInterval startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();

    //Do your thing - dequeue, setup your cell.
    CFTimeInterval endTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    NSLog(@"Cell Creation: %g s", endTime - startTime);
    return cell;
}
```

and wherever you call reloadData()

```
    CFTimeInterval startTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    CFTimeInterval endTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    NSLog(@"Cell Creation: %g s", endTime - startTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

> but it's tough to notice subtle gains by eye.

Don't try. Use Instruments! That's what it's for. The Core Animation instrument will tell you the FPS when you scroll, which is exactly what you want to know here. And the Time Profiling instrument will tell you exactly where in your code the time is being spent.

Don't guess. Don't eyeball. Don't add your own timing instrumentation. Use Instruments!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the mach absolute time for the most accurate results. there is a good explanation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/_index.html

example code:

```
uint64_t startTime = mach_absolute_time();

// do work here


uint64_t endTime = mach_absolute_time();
uint64_t elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;

mach_timebase_info_data_t sTimebaseInfo;
mach_timebase_info(&sTimebaseInfo);
uint32_t numer = sTimebaseInfo.numer;
uint32_t denom = sTimebaseInfo.denom;
uint64_t elapsedNano = (elapsedTime * numer / denom);
NSTimeInterval elapsedSeconds =  elapsedNano / (CGFloat)NSEC_PER_SEC;


NSLog(@"elapsed time: %f", elapsedSeconds);
```